# Particle interaction with environment and objects in scene

Tags: c++, ogre, particle-system

I've create a ParticleSystem in Ogre so that my object emitt, suppose, a lot of star.

My question is: how can I realize the interaction of this stars with the environment and the objects in the scene too? but more importantly, can I do this issue with ParticleSystem?

Any help will be appreciated!

**update**

I'm trying to use inside my particle file:

```
affector DeflectorPlane {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DeflectorPlane supports as the name suggests only a single plane of which particles can bounce of (see entry in [Ogre manual](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_40.html#DeflectorPlane-Affector)).

Having particles bounce of arbitrary surfaces involves a lot of heavy collision detection and is therefore a task that is not in the responsibility of a rending but a physics engine, hence Ogre3D has no out-of-the-box support for this requirement.

But there are four different options in terms of already existing Ogre3D physics engine wrappers: Newton, Bullet, PhysX and ODE. Each of the wrappers has its own dedicated section in the [Ogre Addons forum](http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/) with further information and links.